# how to implement certificate based authentication for Microsoft Bot Framework v4 bot in the code using .netcore?

Tags: azure-bot-service, botframework

I'm looking for certificate-based bot authentication. I found some approach in node js as below

`const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({ appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId, useCertificateAuthentication: true, certificateThumbprint: '33***608A6******19***325D*****8****', certificatePrivateKey: certKey }); const fs = require('fs'); var certKey = fs.readFileSync('./DEV-private.key').toString()` .

If you see the above piece of code there instead of app password we are using a certificate for app id authentication of the bot.
But I just want to implement the same in .netcore 3.1. I'm not able to find any reference on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework Adapter incorporates the Authentication library for setting up authentication via a certificate. You can see which classes and properties are used and/or available by referencing Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication in the botframework-dotnet repo, in particular the [AdalAuthenticator](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Authentication/AdalAuthenticator.cs) class. You can see how it is used and what properties are passed in the [BotFramework Adapter](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs).